# Curl: How to send custom headers while using proxy

Tags: curl

I want to send custom headers to the host while using proxies. Take a look at the examples below. Explaining the situation with examples was easier.

This works fine as expected:

```
curl https://www.cloudflare.com/
```

---

When I choose to avoid using DNS by giving host's IP address to curl:

```
curl http://198.41.214.163/
```

Website gives me this error page -->

> "**Direct IP access not allowed.** You've requested an IP address that is
>   part of the CloudFlare network. *A valid Host header must be supplied*
>   to reach the desired website."

---

If we supply correct host header name, it will work normal again without using DNS:

```
curl --header "Host: cloudflare.com" http://198.41.214.163/
```

---

But when I do the same while using a proxy tunnel, curl doesn't send the headers to host, so i get "**Direct IP access not allowed**" error from to the host:

```
curl --proxy "http://PROXY_IP:PORT" --header "Host: cloudflare.com" http://198.41.214.163/
```

---

How can i overcome this problem?

Answer (score 6):

This problem should be gone with cURL 7.37.0, which introduced the `--proxy-header` parameter to specify headers that are meant for the proxy server. Headers given with `-H`/`--header` will be seen as "end-server only" now.